# Is there a dictionary comprehension that can retrieve key-values for each row of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have created a pandas dataframe that has two columns, "x_ticks" and "y_ticks". This stores information about the tick marks for graphical images.

Each row is a dictionary of the 'id' and tick points of each image.

[image: Tick Mark Dataframe]

A singular row looks like this:

[image]

Is there a method that can retrieve the 'x' and 'y' values of the key 'tick_pt', in each row of the dataframe, for the respective columns "x_ticks" and "y_ticks"?

How can these x and y values then be stored as two new separate columns in the df?

An attempt:

```
# Iterate over each row
for _, row in df():
    
    # Get the list of points
    points_list = row["Points"][0]

    # Iterate over each point
    for i, point in enumerate(points_list):
        # Create a new row with the point coordinates
        new_row = {'X': point['x'], 'Y': point['y']}
```

This looks somewhat promising but I haven't found a method that actually gets the list of x and y points ('tick_pt').

Comment: Please don't use images to present data.  Present it as text.  For example, use `print(df)` to show a dataframe or `df.to_dict()`. If you do this then we can reconstruct the dataframe.

Comment: You might want to replace `for _, row in df():` with `for _, row in df.iterrows():` so that your code runs.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Noted @Bill. I see, `iterrows()` might be what I'm looking for. Once I run the code, there seems to be an issue with accessing the `"tick_pt"` when trying to get the list of points, `points_list = row["tick_pt"][0] `.

Comment: The error log: # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'tick_pt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily like this using apply method:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_ticks': [{'id': 'A', 'tick_pt': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}},
                               {'id': 'B', 'tick_pt': {'x': 3, 'y': 4}},
                               {'id': 'C', 'tick_pt': {'x': 5, 'y': 6}}],
                   'y_ticks': [{'id': 'A', 'tick_pt': {'x': 7, 'y': 8}},
                               {'id': 'B', 'tick_pt': {'x': 9, 'y': 10}},
                               {'id': 'C', 'tick_pt': {'x': 11, 'y': 12}}]})


df['X.x'] = df['x_ticks'].apply(lambda row: row['tick_pt']['x'])
df['X.y'] = df['x_ticks'].apply(lambda row: row['tick_pt']['y'])
df['Y.x'] = df['y_ticks'].apply(lambda row: row['tick_pt']['x'])
df['Y.y'] = df['y_ticks'].apply(lambda row: row['tick_pt']['y'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                    x_ticks  \
0  {'id': 'A', 'tick_pt': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}}   
1  {'id': 'B', 'tick_pt': {'x': 3, 'y': 4}}   
2  {'id': 'C', 'tick_pt': {'x': 5, 'y': 6}}   

                                      y_ticks  X.x  X.y  Y.x  Y.y  
0    {'id': 'A', 'tick_pt': {'x': 7, 'y': 8}}    1    2    7    8  
1   {'id': 'B', 'tick_pt': {'x': 9, 'y': 10}}    3    4    9   10  
2  {'id': 'C', 'tick_pt': {'x': 11, 'y': 12}}    5    6   11   12
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense. This works well when I use a subset/sample of the df. But when I use it on the whole df, I receive a "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error?

Comment: I think my above comment might have to do with the fact that in my df, there are several of these dictionaries, {'id': 'A', 'tick_pt': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}}, in each row (I have shown what a single row of my df looks like). Perhaps I should make each row fit one dictionary only, then use your apply method? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: yes each record should have one dictionary you can do it like `row[0]['tick_pt']['x']` and `row[0]['tick_pt']['y']` in the above code to get just first element of the list

Comment: @RaphaNash please accept it as a correct answer and give an upvote if It helps

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic is unclear, but you can convert to a long format using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
tmp = df.explode(['x_ticks', 'y_ticks'])

out = pd.concat({col: pd.json_normalize(tmp[col]) for col in tmp},
                axis=1).set_axis(tmp.index)
```

Output:

```
  x_ticks                     y_ticks                    
       id tick_pt.x tick_pt.y      id tick_pt.x tick_pt.y
0      13        77       186      13        55        51
0      14       117       186      14       155       151
1       9       101       248       3        63        45
1      14       117       186       4       163       145
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_ticks': [[{'id': 13, 'tick_pt': {'x': 77, 'y': 186}}, {'id': 14, 'tick_pt': {'x': 117, 'y': 186}}],
                               [{'id': 9, 'tick_pt': {'x': 101, 'y': 248}}, {'id': 14, 'tick_pt': {'x': 117, 'y': 186}}],
                              ],
                   'y_ticks': [[{'id': 13, 'tick_pt': {'x': 55, 'y': 51}}, {'id': 14, 'tick_pt': {'x': 155, 'y': 151}}],
                               [{'id': 3, 'tick_pt': {'x': 63, 'y': 45}}, {'id': 4, 'tick_pt': {'x': 163, 'y': 145}}],
                              ]
                  })
```